# How to set Jasper element level property using Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to set the property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row` at design time as I need to set it dynamically for each Jasper Element in my report.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
  <reportElement key="amountTranserBasicAmountTransferFDIBenebankaddress2" style="ColumnHeader" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="60" y="0" width="30" height="14" uuid="c2ecdd7e-1ce2-4d57-af03-f32ae6234dad">
   <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
</reportElement>
```

Could somebody point out me a way to do it through Java?

Answer (score 2):

For all version 4.x and higher, you can pass an expression instead of hard coding a value for a property in the jrxml using `propertyExpression`, hence there is no need for you to do complicate the report re-elaborating via java.

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row"><![CDATA[$F{isFitTrue}]] ></propertyExpression>
```

In the example `$F{isFitTrue}` is a field that will have the value "true" or "false", it can also be an parameter or a variable.

If anyway you like to do via java with the **[`JasperDesign`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html)** object use the [`JRDesignPropertyExpression`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignPropertyExpression.html) as in example:

```
JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
JRDesignPropertyExpression propertyExpression = new JRDesignPropertyExpression();
propertyExpression.setName(JRXlsAbstractExporter.PROPERTY_AUTO_FIT_ROW);
JRDesignExpression expr = new JRDesignExpression();
expr.setValueClass(java.lang.String.class);
expr.setText("true");
propertyExpression.setValueExpression(expr);
textField.addPropertyExpression(propertyExpression);
```

Comment: I tried to set the property using JasperDesign as suggested above. It gives me "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String". It is perhaps expecting us to set boolean value. But JRDesignEcpression does not seem to have constructor which accepts boolean value.

Comment: @Smitesh Unfortunatly I can't test your code, but I have updated the post, with the old setValueClass expression (I think it should be String, otherwise test with boolean), let me know